How to enable eslint inline config in Next.js
I’m working on a Next.js project with TypeScript. It needs to interface with an external JavaScript library that isn’t TypeScript-enabled, which I’m loading by means of Next’s <Script> component. It works fine in development, but when I try to build it, the build fails with the error Type error: Cannot find name 'x'., where x is an object from the external library. I’ve tried declaring types for it but that’s a lot of very fiddly work for little gain, since it’s a well tested library. I’d like to just suppress the lint errors for the problem lines, but I can’t seem to get it working. Here’s what I’ve tried:

Include inline comments per eslint’s documentation.
// eslint-disable-next-line
const y = new x.constructor();

or
const y = new x.constructor(); // eslint-disable-line

(I left this in while trying the rest of this list, since it didn’t work by itself.)
Override Next’s default eslint rules, by creating .eslintrc.json with contents:
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "next/typescript"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.mts"],
      "rules": {
        "no-inline-config": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Modify Next’s eslint config by creating next.config.js with contents:
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    "no-online-config": "off",
  },
}

(This throws a warning, Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'noInlineConfig' at "eslint".)
Hack node_modules/next/bin/dist/bin/next and remove the code .option("--no-inline-config", "Prevents comments from changing config or rules.").

None of these made any difference, except for option 3, which threw a warning. For obvious reasons I don’t want to disable eslint completely, but I can’t see another option if I want this to build. What am I missing?
package.json:
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.0",
    "@mui/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^7.17.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.16.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.13",
    "next": "^14.2.12",
    "nuqs": "^1.20.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.8",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}



Type error: Cannot find name 'x'

That's not an ESLint report. That's a TypeScript report. Your whole investigation is going down the wrong path. 
ESLint and TypeScript are both tools that give feedback on your code without running it (this is called "static analysis"). But they're two very tools:

ESLint runs a configurable set of individual rules, many of which can be loaded in by plugins such as eslint-plugin-next
TypeScript is a general-purpose type checker that reports when the way you use values in code mismatches its understanding of what's available to be used + how (the "type system")

Any report starting with "Type error:" is a TypeScript type error. The way to suppress TypeScript type errors is with an inline // @ts-expect-error (preferred) or // @ts-ignore (less preferable). See https://www.totaltypescript.com/concepts/how-to-use-ts-expect-error for a good explanation.

Aside: instead of suppressing the TypeScript type error, it would be better to tell TypeScript about x existing. That way it can give dev-time assistance for x & let you know if you're using it wrong. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html has docs. For example, to declare x as a constant object with a .constructor:
declare const x: {
  constructor: typeof Object; // or typeof whatever class
}

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gDwFzwG8AoeUxVTGAVzAyRnwwE8AHEJAM3gHkAjAK3AYA3EQC+ooihAB3HADpk6DNVr0AFAEphQA

That solved it! Appreciate you explaining the difference between TypeScript errors and ESLint errors... it's obvious in retrospect, but since I was also dealing with a load of ESLint errors during the build process, it didn't occur to me that this error was different. Initially I did try something like your alternative suggestion, declaring a class structure, but it quickly got too complicated. I'll have a go later with the constructor declaration and see how I get on. Thanks!

Yay, glad it's working out!
